# Angular CORS OAuth2 wont let me in

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, cors

I want to authenticate on an external server to get some data. When I try to authenticate, I get a Cors error. I also have a proxy.conf.json but it doesn't seem to work

Code:

```
  authUrl = "http://localhost:4200/auth"
  tokenUrl = "http://localhost:4200/tokenUrl"
  redirect_uri = "http://localhost:4200"
    
auth(clientId: string, secredId: string) {


    const url = this.authUrl + '?client_id=' + clientId + '&response_type=code&scope=' + this.scope + '&state=' + this.state + '&redirect_uri=' + this.redirect_uri

    this.http.get<void>(url, this.httpOptions).subscribe(() => {
      const code = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('code');
      // go on
    });
```

conf:

```
      {
        "/auth": {
        "target": "https://www.EXTERNAL_WWW_APP.com/oauth2/authorize",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
          "^/auth": ""
        }
      },
      "/tokenUrl": {
        "target": "https://www.EXTERNAL_WWW_APP.com/oauth2/token",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
          "^/tokenUrl": ""
        }
      }
```

Error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.EXTERNAL_WWW_APP.com/login?return=34sdf34AasdIZU' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4200/auth?client_id=1&response_type=code&scope=read&state=aakjsdh&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

`GET https://www.EXTERNAL_WWW_APP.com/login?return=c3f456tij47fztMJTZM net::ERR_FAILED`

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in the backend, not in Angular. The fix depends on your backend solution. For example, in a .NET 6 web app, you would need something like this in your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    var frontEndUrl = "your frontend url here";
    var allowedOrigins = new[] { frontEndUrl };
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
```

Comment: So if I don't have rights to change it on the external server, can I forget?
the authorization works with my django backend